# Netbook won't boot after using EasyBCD

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, easybcd

I have an Asus T91MT netbook on which I used to have Windows 7 Home Premium and Ubuntu 10.10 installed (dual boot).

After trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04, Ubuntu is no longer able to boot, so I tried to uninstall Ubuntu completely and then reinstall it. Following these directions, I tried using EasyBCD to bypass the GRUB2 bootloader so that after uninstalling, it would automatically boot into Windows 7.

However, after doing the "install BCD" step and restarting, I got the following message:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \Boot\BCD

  Status: 0xc0000098

  Info: The Windows Boot Configuration Data file does not contain a valid OS entry.
```

I'm currently trying to create a USB stick of the Windows Installation disc but in the mean time, I can only boot from a Ubuntu USB stick.

Is there anything I can do from within Ubuntu to fix this? Or does anyone have any other suggestions/solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help you.
You can boot Windows again using the Ubuntu live CD:

1. Boot the Ubuntu Live CD or USB
2. Enter Disk Manager
3. Mark the disk that Windows is currently installed on as active
4. Wait for a couple of minutes
5. Reboot

If everything goes well you should be able to boot again. That's the way I resolved this issue on my own computer. If it doesn't work, you could try using the Windows repair disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can try booting off any Windows 7 disk to get to the command line. After which a simple `bootrec /RebuildBcd` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If the old BCD cannot be found, chances are your partition layout changed, either deliberately or done by the Ubuntu installer. Try to roll back the partition changes, or use the repair console on a Windows 7 installation DVD and enter:

- bootsect /NT60 ALL /force
- bootrec /RebuildBcd

This prevents you from booting your old Ubuntu installation, but you can repair that at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

boot you notebook with windows 7 and choose `Repair your computer` and `startup repair` and then the windows seven bootmenu will be installed then add your ubuntu with easybcd to `windows 7 bootloader`

Answer (score -1):

Easybcd is using its own bootloader and so creating problems. There is no need of third party boot loader. GRUB2 and Windows boot loader are enough for dual-booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

You can use this tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows to repair dual-booting.

Comment: EasyBCD doesn't use "its own bootloader." It only configures the Windows boot loader.

Comment: And what is neogrub used for ? For configuring Windows boot loader ?

Comment: NeoGrub doesn't get installed. It can (optionally) sit in the middle as a bridge between BOOTMGR and GRUB2.

Comment: @Mahmoud Can you explain what exactly EasyBCD creates/configures to load say Ubuntu/GRUB2 ? Is some kind of third party boot loader involved ? What is ANGn (size>200kb) ? Some modification of Grub4dos ?

Comment: @Mahmoud Thank you for hiding information. It is exactly Grub4dos with minimalist changes. So EasyBCD is using 3 boot managers (bootmgr, grub4dos + grub ) to chainload Linux OS. And you call Grub4dos a bridge ? Ha-ha-ha !